# with NSInvocation causing SIGABRT

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, invocation

I've followed a few tutorials and I cant seem to adapt them to my needs. 
Simply I have a manager objects that returns a `NSInvocation` to be stored and invoked at a later point in the app.

and when I run the application, my method signature is null and even trying to assign a `NSInvocation` from a getter is causing a `SIGABRT`.

```
@interface Cars : NSObject
+ (NSArray *)all;
@end
```

cars all method just returns an array "1","2","3","4".
and in my object manager I do this:

```
- (NSInvocation *) cars_ALL {

    NSMethodSignature *ca   = [Cars instanceMethodSignatureForSelector:@selector(all)];
    NSLog(@"%@", ca);

    return [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:ca];
}
```

and I call it like this:

```
NSInvocation *cinv = [myObjectManager cars_ALL];
```

thats it, im not even up to invoking or assigning the target etc of the invocation.
anything I try just doesn't work out.

Comment: It would help to know what problem you're trying to solve; chances are this is neither the simplest nor the best approach.

Comment: I recommend to use blocks instead of NSInvocation.

Comment: hrmmm im not sure if that will work?
my vision for this is to somehow save an invocation for later use,
so i dont need to know what model object i need to call Instead i simply create my object with the correct model invocation and use it as i please? im open to suggestions i just thought of using NSInvocation